# Magento Custom Query to add variables to the email subject and body

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I am trying to get a custom value from sales_flat_order for gpname and assign a custom var for email subjects to send.

my query code

```
$read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$gproductname = $read->fetchOne("select gpname from sales_flat_order where entity_id =".$orderid);
```

yes the $orderid is correct and passed to the query.
but the $gpoductname is empty, and the value exists in db.

this query is placed in sendNewOrderEmail() order.php.

Update:
the above code is good the query is executing but the issue was that the gpname cell was empty when the query was made.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try with:

```
$order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
$order->addAttributeToSelect('gpname');
$order->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',array('eq'=>$orderId));
$gproductname =$order->getFirstItem();
```

Comment: Thank you i found the issue, the gpname was empty when the query was made.
this code is good and the query is executing just fine.